# sitemesh + spring security: show logged in user in main decorator page!

Tags: spring-security, sitemesh

I want to show logged in user in main decorator page.
i use :

```
<decorator:usePage id="myPage"/>
Logged in as:<%= myPage.getRequest().getUserPrincipal().getName()%>
<decorator:body/>
```

but not work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to place the SiteMesh filter-mapping below the Spring Security filter mapping.

See: [Spring security tags in sitemesh decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370629/spring-security-tags-in-sitemesh-decorator#4370767)

Answer (score 0):

Haven't worked with SiteMesh for quite some time, but why aren't you using the implicit `request` object instead (I assume your pages are written in JSP, right?)

```
<%= request.getUserPrincipal().getName() %>
```

And what's exactly not working? Is an exception getting thrown?