# spring security 3.1 isAuthenticated() not working

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm starting a new project with spring mvc 3 and spring security 3.1.0. 
I coded a Authentication provider, a UserDetails class. Very simple.
The authentication is working properly, but when i use in my jsp (template one using sitemesh) it seems that it doesn´t work a all.

Here is my example.

```
<security:authorize access="isAuthenticated()"> 
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li class="${selectedMenu.equals('index') ? 'active' : ''}"><a href="<c:url value="/" />">Home</a></li>
                    ....            
                </ul>
            </security:authorize>
            <p class="navbar-text pull-right">Logged in as <a href="#"><security:authentication property="principal.username"/></a></p>
```

i never see the ul and  is blank..

I don´t know what i missing

Here is my configuration:

security-applicationContext.xml

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <http pattern="/resources/**" security="none"/>
    <http use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isFullyAuthenticated()" />
         <form-login login-page='/spring_security_login' default-target-url='/index.html'
            always-use-default-target='true' />
        <session-management session-fixation-protection="none" />

    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="AuthRepository">
            <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder"/>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

UserDetails

```
package ar.com.held.auth;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;

import ar.com.held.model.User;



public class UserDetails implements org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails {

        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -2636146093986968636L;

        private User user;

        private String userName;
        private String password;

        public User getUser() {
            return user;
        }

        public UserDetails(User user){
                this.user = user;
                this.userName = user.getUsername();
                this.password = user.getPassword();
        }

        @Override
        public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
                return new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        }

        @Override
        public String getPassword() {
                return this.password;
        }

        @Override
        public String getUsername() {
                return this.userName;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
                return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
                return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
                return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isEnabled() {
                return true;
        }



}
```

AuthRepository

```
package ar.com.held.auth;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import ar.com.held.model.User;
import ar.com.held.repository.UserRepository;


/***
 * Authentication users repository
 * 
 *
 */
@Repository(value="AuthRepository")
public class AuthRepository extends JdbcDaoImpl {

        @Autowired
        private UserRepository userRepository;

        @Override
        public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
                        throws UsernameNotFoundException {
                User user = userRepository.findByUserName(username);
                if(user==null)
                        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username+" no es un usuario registrado");
                return new ar.com.held.auth.UserDetails(user);
        }

        @Override
        protected void checkDaoConfig() {
        }
}
```

edited***

here is the debug information when i request a JSP page when i am logged in:

```
2012-02-14 18:18:28 AntPathRequestMatcher [DEBUG] Checking match of request : '/companies/list'; against '/resources/**'
2012-02-14 18:18:28 FilterChainProxy [DEBUG] /companies/list at position 1 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2012-02-14 18:18:28 HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository [DEBUG] Obtained a valid SecurityContext from SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT: 'org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@127c16e: Authentication: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@127c16e: Principal: ar.com.held.auth.UserDetails@1250cda; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffd3270: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: 4E06EC71A480C21A3CB08DDE2EBFDAF5; Not granted any authorities'
2012-02-14 18:18:28 FilterChainProxy [DEBUG] /companies/list at position 2 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2012-02-14 18:18:28 FilterChainProxy [DEBUG] /companies/list at position 3 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
2012-02-14 18:18:28 FilterChainProxy [DEBUG] /companies/list at position 4 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter'
2012-02-14 18:18:28 FilterChainProxy [DEBUG] /companies/list at position 5 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
2012-02-14 18:18:28 FilterChainProxy [DEBUG] /companies/list at position 6 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2012-02-14 18:18:28 FilterChainProxy [DEBUG] /companies/list at position 7 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2012-02-14 18:18:28 AnonymousAuthenticationFilter [DEBUG] SecurityContextHolder not populated with anonymous token, as it already contained: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@127c16e: Principal: ar.com.held.auth.UserDetails@1250cda; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffd3270: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: 4E06EC71A480C21A3CB08DDE2EBFDAF5; Not granted any authorities'
2012-02-14 18:18:28 FilterChainProxy [DEBUG] /companies/list at position 8 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
2012-02-14 18:18:28 FilterChainProxy [DEBUG] /companies/list at position 9 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2012-02-14 18:18:28 FilterChainProxy [DEBUG] /companies/list at position 10 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2012-02-14 18:18:28 FilterSecurityInterceptor [DEBUG] Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /companies/list; Attributes: [isFullyAuthenticated()]
2012-02-14 18:18:28 FilterSecurityInterceptor [DEBUG] Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@127c16e: Principal: ar.com.held.auth.UserDetails@1250cda; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffd3270: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: 4E06EC71A480C21A3CB08DDE2EBFDAF5; Not granted any authorities
2012-02-14 18:18:28 AffirmativeBased [DEBUG] Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@10932b8, returned: 1
2012-02-14 18:18:28 FilterSecurityInterceptor [DEBUG] Authorization successful
2012-02-14 18:18:28 FilterSecurityInterceptor [DEBUG] RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
2012-02-14 18:18:28 FilterChainProxy [DEBUG] /companies/list reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
2012-02-14 18:18:28 DispatcherServlet [DEBUG] DispatcherServlet with name 'spring' processing GET request for [/Held/companies/list]
2012-02-14 18:18:28 RequestMappingHandlerMapping [DEBUG] Looking up handler method for path /companies/list
2012-02-14 18:18:28 RequestMappingHandlerMapping [DEBUG] Returning handler method [public java.lang.String ar.com.held.controller.CompanyController.list(org.springframework.ui.Model)]
2012-02-14 18:18:28 DefaultListableBeanFactory [DEBUG] Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'companyController'
2012-02-14 18:18:28 DispatcherServlet [DEBUG] Last-Modified value for [/Held/companies/list] is: -1
2012-02-14 18:18:28 SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler [DEBUG] Creating new EntityManager for shared EntityManager invocation
2012-02-14 18:18:28 SessionImpl [DEBUG] Opened session at timestamp: 13292543088
2012-02-14 18:18:28 LogicalConnectionImpl [DEBUG] Obtaining JDBC connection
2012-02-14 18:18:28 DriverManagerDataSource [DEBUG] Creating new JDBC DriverManager Connection to [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/held]
2012-02-14 18:18:28 LogicalConnectionImpl [DEBUG] Obtained JDBC connection
2012-02-14 18:18:28 SQL [DEBUG] select company0_.id as id7_, company0_.version as version7_, company0_.city as city7_, company0_.state as state7_, company0_.street as street7_, company0_.name as name7_, company0_.owner_id as owner7_7_ from Company company0_ where company0_.owner_id=?
2012-02-14 18:18:28 StatefulPersistenceContext [DEBUG] Initializing non-lazy collections
2012-02-14 18:18:28 EntityManagerFactoryUtils [DEBUG] Closing JPA EntityManager
2012-02-14 18:18:28 LogicalConnectionImpl [DEBUG] Releasing JDBC connection
2012-02-14 18:18:28 LogicalConnectionImpl [DEBUG] Released JDBC connection
2012-02-14 18:18:28 ConnectionProxyHandler [DEBUG] HHH000163: Logical connection releasing its physical connection
2012-02-14 18:18:28 DefaultListableBeanFactory [DEBUG] Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'company/list'
2012-02-14 18:18:28 DefaultListableBeanFactory [DEBUG] Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
2012-02-14 18:18:28 DefaultListableBeanFactory [DEBUG] Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.methodSecurityMetadataSourceAdvisor'
2012-02-14 18:18:28 DefaultListableBeanFactory [DEBUG] Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
2012-02-14 18:18:28 DefaultListableBeanFactory [DEBUG] Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.methodSecurityMetadataSourceAdvisor'
2012-02-14 18:18:28 DispatcherServlet [DEBUG] Rendering view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView: name 'company/list'; URL [/WEB-INF/view/company/list.jsp]] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'
2012-02-14 18:18:28 JstlView [DEBUG] Added model object 'companies' of type [java.util.ArrayList] to request in view with name 'company/list'
2012-02-14 18:18:28 JstlView [DEBUG] Forwarding to resource [/WEB-INF/view/company/list.jsp] in InternalResourceView 'company/list'
2012-02-14 18:18:30 DispatcherServlet [DEBUG] Successfully completed request
2012-02-14 18:18:30 ExceptionTranslationFilter [DEBUG] Chain processed normally
2012-02-14 18:18:30 SecurityContextPersistenceFilter [DEBUG] SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2012-02-14 18:18:30 AntPathRequestMatcher [DEBUG] Checking match of request : '/resources/img/hp_notepad2_mechapencil.ico'; against '/resources/**'
2012-02-14 18:18:30 FilterChainProxy [DEBUG] /resources/img/hp_notepad2_mechapencil.ico has an empty filter list
2012-02-14 18:18:30 DispatcherServlet [DEBUG] DispatcherServlet with name 'spring' processing GET request for [/Held/resources/img/hp_notepad2_mechapencil.ico]
2012-02-14 18:18:30 RequestMappingHandlerMapping [DEBUG] Looking up handler method for path /resources/img/hp_notepad2_mechapencil.ico
2012-02-14 18:18:30 RequestMappingHandlerMapping [DEBUG] Did not find handler method for [/resources/img/hp_notepad2_mechapencil.ico]
2012-02-14 18:18:30 SimpleUrlHandlerMapping [DEBUG] Matching patterns for request [/resources/img/hp_notepad2_mechapencil.ico] are [/resources/**]
2012-02-14 18:18:30 SimpleUrlHandlerMapping [DEBUG] URI Template variables for request [/resources/img/hp_notepad2_mechapencil.ico] are {}
2012-02-14 18:18:30 SimpleUrlHandlerMapping [DEBUG] Mapping [/resources/img/hp_notepad2_mechapencil.ico] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler@1ca2fb0] and 1 interceptor
2012-02-14 18:18:30 DispatcherServlet [DEBUG] Last-Modified value for [/Held/resources/img/hp_notepad2_mechapencil.ico] is: -1
2012-02-14 18:18:30 ResourceHttpRequestHandler [DEBUG] Trying relative path [img/hp_notepad2_mechapencil.ico] against base location: ServletContext resource [/resources/]
2012-02-14 18:18:30 ResourceHttpRequestHandler [DEBUG] Found matching resource: ServletContext resource [/resources/img/hp_notepad2_mechapencil.ico]
2012-02-14 18:18:30 ResourceHttpRequestHandler [DEBUG] Determined media type 'image/x-icon' for ServletContext resource [/resources/img/hp_notepad2_mechapencil.ico]
2012-02-14 18:18:30 ResourceHttpRequestHandler [DEBUG] Resource not modified - returning 304
2012-02-14 18:18:30 DispatcherServlet [DEBUG] Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'spring': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2012-02-14 18:18:30 DispatcherServlet [DEBUG] Successfully completed request
```

---

Can you help me?.. Am i missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll need to provide some more details. What is the URL? What does the debug log contain when you request the JSP?

Comment: i've edited the post with the debug information. Thanks

Comment: Oh.. i see.. thanks to the debug information i did a test.. i wrote <security:authentication property="principal.username"/> on my list.jsp and to my surprise is rendered. So it means i have a problem with my sitemesh template.. because i use sitemesh for templating and the same line in my template is not rendered... I hope be clear....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem was very simple. All the spring security tags were used in a site mesh template. And i have in my web.xml sitemesh configuration first and then spring security configuration.. so it does not work.. it have to be first spring security and then sitemesh.

Here is part of the web.xml

```
<!-- Security -->

    <filter>
      <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
      <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
<!-- end security --> 
<!-- Site Mesh -->

    <filter>
        <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.filter.PageFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

<!-- -->
```

Yo can see a this post: [Spring security tags in sitemesh decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370629/spring-security-tags-in-sitemesh-decorator)

Thanks to Luke Taylor. He asked me for debug information and i realized what happen.