# Spring Security, Sitemesh & Taglibs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, spring-mvc, spring-security, sitemesh

My problem is similar to this one:

[Spring security tags in sitemesh decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370629/spring-security-tags-in-sitemesh-decorator)

I'm using sitemesh in a Spring MVC project with Spring security. My web.xml looks like this:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
  <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
  <filter-class>com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

And my NavBar.jsp (I'm using the Spring MVC Bootstrap showcase), which is included in every page decorated by sitemesh, looks like this:

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">  
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

        <security:authorize ifAnyGranted="ROLE_UPDATE">
            <li ><a href="<c:url value="/dataupdate" />">Update</a></li>
        </security:authorize>

        <security:authorize ifAnyGranted="ROLE_ADMIN">
            <li ><a href="<c:url value="/settings" />">Settings</a></li>
        </security:authorize>

        <li><a href="j_spring_security_logout">Logout</a></li>                           
      </ul>
    </div>
```

All works as expect (i.e. the navbar items only display if the authenticated user has the right roles), but the default Spring Security login page is not decorated. I can fix that by moving the Sitemesh filter in web.xml above the Spring Security filter, however then the security tags in NavBar.jsp stop working.

Is there a way I can have both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this issue I implemented a custom login.jsp page and sitemesh just picked it up.

Answer (score 0):

pelase change the order of the filter and try.. it should work