# Right order of filters in Spring web.xml

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, servlet-filters

I am using four filters in my Spring MVC app and today realized that ordering of filters is also important (fixed decoration issue by referring to [Spring security tags in sitemesh decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370629/spring-security-tags-in-sitemesh-decorator) after wasting good amount of time in debugging). I need help in finding the right order for these filters as I am still learning Spring. Please advise.

My web.xml is:

> http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
>           version="3.1">
>
> ```
> <display-name>Sample App</display-name>
> <description>Sample Application</description>
>
> <context-param>
>     <description>locations of the Spring configuration files</description>
>     <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
>     <param-value>
>       classpath:spring/application-service.xml,
>       classpath:spring/application-servlet.xml,
>       classpath:spring/application-dao.xml,
>       classpath:spring/application-security.xml,
>       classpath:spring/application-social.xml,
>       classpath:spring/application-mailservice.xml,
>     </param-value>
> </context-param>
>
> <listener>
>     <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
> </listener>
>
> <!--- Servlet that dispatches request to registered handlers (Controller implementations). -->
> <servlet>
>     <servlet-name>application</servlet-name>
>     <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
> <init-param>
>     <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
>     <param-value>classpath:spring/application-servlet.xml</param-value>
> </init-param>
>     <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
> </servlet>
>
> <servlet-mapping>
>     <servlet-name>application</servlet-name>
>     <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
> </servlet-mapping>
>
> <filter>
>     <filter-name>httpMethodFilter</filter-name>
>     <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-class>
> </filter>
>
> <filter-mapping>
>     <filter-name>httpMethodFilter</filter-name>
>     <servlet-name>application</servlet-name>
> </filter-mapping>
>   <!-- Enables Spring Security -->
> <filter>
>     <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
>     <filter-class>
>         org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
>     </filter-class>
> </filter>
>
> <filter-mapping>
>     <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
>     <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
> </filter-mapping>
>
> <filter>
>   <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
>   <filter-class>org.sitemesh.config.ConfigurableSiteMeshFilter</filter-class>
> </filter>
>     <filter-mapping>
>   <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
>   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>     </filter-mapping>
>
> <filter>
>     <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
>     <filter-class>
>         org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter
>     </filter-class>
>     <init-param>
>         <param-name>encoding</param-name>
>         <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
>     </init-param>
> </filter>
>
> <filter-mapping>
>     <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
>     <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
> </filter-mapping>
> ```

Comment: are you getting any error because of this order? If not don't worry.

Comment: i am not getting any error but wanted to avoid future issues... anyway, i will keep it like this till the time I land up in some issue :)